# Multiple examples in scenario outline gives error(Missing EOF at examples:) in eclipse IDE, How can i solve this?

Tags: java, api, cucumber, rest-assured-jsonpath

Scenario Outline: Given.. When.. Then..

```
@test 1
Examples:
    |      Model     | Version | Fuel   |
    |      Honda     | Brio    | Petrol | 
  
@test 2
Examples:    
    |      Model     | Version | Fuel   |                           
    |      Maruti    | LXI     | Diesel |
```

Scenario Outline: Given.. When.. Then..

```
@test 1
Examples:
    |  a | b  | c   |
    | a1 | b1 | c1  | 

@test 2   
    Examples:    
    |      a     | b      | c  |                           
    |      a2    | b2     | c2 |
```

**Problem Statement :**
-> I have multiple scenarios outline so i want when my scenario 1 will run with first row data set than it will further move to scenario 2 and pick the first row data set and continue to proceed with scenario 3, 4 with first row data set only. Once this flow completed, than again Scenario Outline 1 will run now this time it should pick second set of data which is present in its second row and further proceed to scenario 2 and pick this time second row data set and continue to proceed with scenario 3 and 4 with its second set of data only.

**Note:-**

```
@test1  //Error here -"mismatch input '@test1' expecting examples"
Examples: //Error here if i remove tags -"missing EOF at examples"
```

Comment: Could you please share the line of code where you are passing the tags. The problem might be there

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug in the [cucumber-eclipse](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse) gherkin parser. I recommend you submit a bug report.